# How to read all nonempty csv files into list in R

Tags: r

I would like to read a bunch of csvs into a list in R

```
lol<-lapply(list.files()[c(grep(Sys.Date(),list.files()))],read.csv)
```

Some csv files are empty though so I get

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
```

(at least I think the error means)

How do I read the nonempty csv files into a list?

`tryCatch` does not work (or I am using it wrong)

```
tryCatch(toplel<-lapply(list.files()[c(grep(Sys.Date(),list.files()))],read.csv),error=function(e){print("lel")})
[1] "lel"
```

Comment: move `tryCatch` into your inner expression and use an anonymous function, e.g. `function(x) tryCatch(read.csv(x), error = print(1e1))` instead of `read.csv`

Comment: Could you rewrite your answer for my problem? I can't seem to figure out what x should be

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try excluding empty files by their size:

```
files <- list.files()[c(grep(Sys.Date(),list.files()))]
files <- files[which(file.info(files)$size>0)]

lapply(files, read.csv)
```

Comment: Ahhh... thank you. This was an easier solution for me to implement in my loop. I didn't know about the "file.info" command. Great!!